# Removing multiple lines

Tags: command-line, sed, json

I am trying to write up a command line interfaces that will removes a particular section / lines of codes within a list of json files. By the way, the json file are located within the sub-folders of the main directory

I am pretty new to this but this is the code that I can come up with so far - `find -name "*.json" | xargs sed -i "map"` but some of the json files I had, its format is slightly different

So far I am seeing the following 2 formats within my list:

```
{
    "tags": {}, 
    "map": {
        "KPA": {
            "State": True, 
            "namespace": "KPA01"
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "tags": {
        "type": [
            "char"
        ], 
        "dynamic": true
    }, 
    "map": {
        "KPA01": {
           "State": True, 
            "namespace": "KPA01"
        }
    }
}
```

and basically, I am trying to omit out the map section that it has, so that it will only display the tags section but the presence of commas and `[]` / `{}` are making it hard for me.
So my output results should be like this:

```
{
    "tags": {}
}
```

or

```
{
    "tags": {
        "type": [
            "char"
        ], 
        "dynamic": true
    }
}
```

Will this be possible to do so in a command line interface? I heard that jq may be able to do it, however, as I tried executing `jq '.map' test.json` I am getting `parse error: ':' not as part of an object at line 2, column 11` in my terminal. Likewise it also seems to be giving off error if I am using the [jq play](https://jqplay.org/) online..

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a very good idea to parse hierarchical markup languages (html/xml/json) with string processors that are not aware of the syntax. It always goes wrong somewhere (you can quickly see that you'd have to actually count braces to make this right in general). It would be much better to actually load json as an object, remove the property and output it again. I'd go for python. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, change `True` to `true`. As a whole, this works very well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(inputfile,'r') as myfile:
    obj = json.loads(myfile.read().replace('True','true'))
    if "map" in obj:
        del obj["map"]
    json.dump(obj,sys.stdout,indent=4,separators=(',',': '))
```

This writes to standard output.

EDIT: the previous in-place version seemed to be somewhat dangerous. Better do it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
with open(inputfile,'r') as myfile:
    obj = json.loads(myfile.read().replace('True','true'))
    if "map" in obj:
        del obj["map"]
with open(inputfile,'w') as myfile:
    json.dump(obj,myfile,indent=4,separators=(',',': '))
```

Because the script is actually aware of what a valid JSON is, it will throw an exception if it encounters invalid code, instead of producing unpredictable output.

This works on python 3, just so you know.

EDIT2:

You can modify the objects in any way you like, the purpose of Json is exactly serialization of objects. Treat them as associative arrays and give them any value you want. For instance, you can do this:

```
#add a new string on the "ground" level
obj["new_key"]="lol"
#add a new subarray, with properties of different types
obj["this_is_array"]={"a": 3, "b": 16, "c": "string", "d": False }
#modify the value of existing field
obj["new_key"]="new value"
#insert into subarray (test if it exists first)
if "this_is_array" in obj:
    obj["this_is_array"]["e"]=42
```

Comment: Pardon me. How am I suppose to run this? Run it within the directory `python <Name of this script>`?

Comment: Either `python <name of this script> <name of your json file>` or just make it executable (`chmod +x <script file>`) and call it as `./script.py <json file>`. The second variant modifies each file in place, so make a backup of json files before using it just in case.

Comment: Is this not possible for it to run thru the directory? I have a massive list of json files to process :x

Comment: This processes one file, it's much more flexible this way; you can loop through any set of chosen files in commandline. For instance,

`for file in *.json; do ./script.py "$file"; done`, or `find -name '*.json' -exec ./script.py '{}' ';'` if you have them in many subdirectories.

Comment: So when I tried the first code, whether it is `r` or `r+`, it doesn't seems to appends the changes to the file despite terminal is showing the correct output. However as I tried your second code, it either wipes out all the contents or throw this error - `IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` in `myfile.truncate(0)`

Comment: The first one is MEANT to write to the terminal, I told you that. That's in case you wanted to redirect the output by yourself, or just observe the results. As for the second one, I'm not sure what's wrong. It works on my test environment perfectly. After reading, you truncate the file to length 0 and write the new version. All in-place code is dangerous, that's why I posted also the first version that is safe to test with.

Comment: @dissidia I changed it, now it just reopens the file for writing. It should be safer now.

Comment: Cool, thanks, now it is working. By the way you are missing `del obj["map"]` after the `obj` statement. Okay, I am going to try for a directory scenario, hopefully it works

Comment: Hmm, though it seems to be working and getting rid of the `map` but if I am running throughout the directory, I am seeing `KeyError : 'map'` in terminal. But even before that, I am getting traceback error from `/python2.6/json/decoder.py`

Comment: That happens if 'map' is not even there. But that should be ok, it crashes before it writes the file so it just leaves it alone. That's because this is quick-and-dirty minimal code, I didn't do any heavy error checking. I'm fixing it above. Now it should produce no errors.

Comment: Just a quick qns, will it be the same way if I had wanted to insert a new line?

Comment: @dissidia You can modify or add fields however you like, see my last edit.

Comment: This is really cool. Was wondering if there is a docs for such flags/commands like `["e"]`?

Comment: Refer to the python documentation. This is pretty standard notation for getting elements of associative arrays (just like y[4] is 4-th element of y if y is a regular list/array, so y["s"] is the value in dictionary y under the key "s").

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the *True* > *true* as mentioned elsewhere and get the `jq` tool, you can just do:

```
jq '{tags}' <infile
```

For example, after copying one of your examples to my clipboard:

```
xsel -bo | sed 's/True/true/g' | jq '{tags}'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
{
  "tags": {
    "type": [
      "char"
    ],
    "dynamic": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found same error:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 5, column 26
```

and I'm not used to [json](/questions/tagged/json) but I think `True` should be in smallcase, as `true`, so you can run a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner to fix it and then use `jq` to filter out the `map` key, like:

```
perl -pe 's/(\W)T(rue)/$1t$2/g' file1.json | ./jq 'del(.map)'
```

for first example, that yields:

```
{
  "tags": {}
}
```

and:

```
perl -pe 's/(\W)T(rue)/$1t$2/g' file2.json | ./jq 'del(.map)'
```

for the second one, that yields:

```
{
  "tags": {
    "type": [
      "char"
    ],
    "dynamic": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I am actually trying to run the command directly on a directory that contains a massive list of such json files. Not to mention that the said files are all located in a folder of its own. As such, it will be pretty tedious if I were to run code by code depending on the format

Comment: @dissidia: This is Unix, so I assume you can run a `find` command to get all your `json` files and pipe them to the `perl` command.

Comment: Sorry for this noob question, while the output results displayed in the Terminal is correct, however it is not reflecting the changes as it should be in the actual file. Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, using `find -name "*.json"` does not seems to work... I keep getting `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0`

Answer (score 0):

question is old, however for completeness of options, here's [jtc](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc) based solution:

```
bash $ jtc -pw'<map>l+0' input.json
{
   "tags": {
      "dynamic": true,
      "type": [
         "char"
      ]
   }
}
bash $
```

- it will find all labels `"map"` and purge'em all (while preserving the rest of json)